# broadcast receiver and service gone in loop

Tags: android

i have created a service which detects screen on and off. Now I have a toast that shows when the screen is on. Now when i pass an activity through it is behaving erratically. For example if the screen is shut off and unlocked again it shows the toast perfectly. But when i am passing an intent it shows of continuously...this is the code...

```
package com.androidexample.screenonoff;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AEScreenOnOffService extends Service {
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver=null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service on create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Register receiver that handles screen on and screen off logic
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
            mReceiver = new AEScreenOnOffReceiver();
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        }


        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) { 

            boolean screenOn = true;

            try{
                // Get ON/OFF values sent from receiver ( AEScreenOnOffReceiver.java ) 
                screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);

            }catch(Exception e){}

             //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service on start :"+screenOn, 
                    //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (!screenOn) {

                // your code here
                // Some time required to start any service
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Screen on, ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } else {

                Intent yourintent = new Intent(this, shoad.class);
                yourintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(yourintent);
                // your code here
                // Some time required to stop any service to save battery consumption
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Screen off,", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {

            Log.i("ScreenOnOff", "Service  distroy");
            if(mReceiver!=null)
             unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

        }
}
```

Comment: do you stop your service anywhere

Comment: no i am not....i want it to run in the background

Comment: What do you mean by saying "it shows of continuously"?

Comment: when i unlock the screen it shows. now when i see the recent list it shows again....now ehen i minimize everything and remove the app from the recent history and stare at the phone it starts again...